# not able to open port in googlecloud

Tags: centos, port, google-cloud-platform

i am configuring voip server on centos 7 (google cloude) but some ports are blocked .
I disabled Firewall in centos 
I added firewall rule to google networking.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJykl.png) 
plz help m new to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it properly. Also, you can enable your Firewall in centos and just open the required ports.

To make sure that these ports are in fact open now and available to you, you should try running a small sample server on that port and try to access it from outside on that same port. If you can do so, then the networking part is done. Rest should be configured on your VOIP side.

Comment: But sir after config mention in my question m not able the ping the ports